# Opening an existing google sheet then copying its contents including cell format into another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So here's the gist of what i want to do:

1. I have 2 google sheet files. A clean template (clean sheet) and a sheet with data (data sheet)
2. I want to open the data sheet -> copy the table from the 'main data tab' -> paste it into the clean sheet including the cell formatting
3. Close the data sheet

Is this possible with appscript? I tried searching in google but it only directs me to Query and IMPORTRANGE which only returns values and do not include cell formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following actions sequence:

1. [Insert new sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet()) into the source spreadsheet.
2. [Copy required range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed) to the inserted sheet. Use [CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type) to copy both values and format.
3. [Copy inserted sheet to the target spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) and [delete it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet) in the source.

As a result you will have a source range full copy inside clean sheet in the target spreadsheet. You can also copy this range inside target spreadsheet in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the it starts with the clean file first. With the data file still closed. So i need to open and access the data file first before start copying and i want this to be automated too. With your answer, i think you assumed that the data file is already opened.

Comment: It makes no difference (for the script) which file is open first. Important is only to have both files **references** and sufficient **permissions** to read/write data. The script can access a file by ID or as active spreadsheet, and you can choose where to place the code (both containers are available, or it may be standalone). I see no problem in open/close sequence.

Comment: Do you have the code for referencing/opening another google sheet? In the #1 you indicated, it's only for inserting new sheet.